# Convert DMS to DD

Tags: python, type-conversion, converters

I would like to convert decimal degrees into sexagesimal degrees, at the level of calculations I based myself on this site and this is my code

```
def dec_dms(deg, dec):
    mnt = dec * 60
    dec = mnt%1
    mnt = mnt - dec
    dec = dec * 60
    return deg, mnt, dec

print(dec_dms(12,345))

>>>(12, 20700, 0)
```

the problem is the result which should be (12, 20, 42)
Can you help me please ?

Comment: Please spell out what you expect `dec = mnt%1` to accomplish.

Comment: dec = mnt%1 must leave only the numbers after the decimal point

Answer (score 0):

Your code is supposed to work with the decimal part of the degree. So for the decimal degree **12.345**, you should multiply 60 by the decimal part which should be **0.345** and not **345**

So either you send **0.345** as parameter to your function or you add a leading **0.** to your number.
Here is a way to do the latter :

```
def dec_dms(deg, dec):
    dec = float('.' + str(dec))
    mnt = dec * 60
    dec = mnt % 1
    mnt = mnt - dec
    dec = dec * 60
    return deg, round(mnt), round(dec)

print(dec_dms(12, 345))
```

output:

```
(12, 20, 42)
```